# Are events built on polling?

Tags: event-handling

an event is when you click on something, and code is run right away

polling is when the application constantly checks if your mouse button is held down, and if it's held down in a certain spot, code is run

do events really exist in computing, or is it all a layer built on polling?

Comment: This is really a philosophical question. From the point of view of a software developer, it's not polling if the CPU doesn't have to execute instructions to check if the event has taken place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complicated question, and the answer depends on how far down you go (in abstraction layers) to answer it. Ultimately, your USB keyboard device is being polled once per millisecond by the computer to ask what keys are being held down. This information gets passed to the keyboard driver through a CPU interrupt when the USB device (in the computer) gets a packet of data from the keyboard. From then on, interrupts are used to pass the data from process to process (through the GUI framework) and eventually reach your application.

As Marc Cohen said in his answer, CPU interrupts are also raised to signal I/O completion. This is an example of something which has no polling until you get to the hardware level, where checks are performed (perhaps once per clock cycle? Someone with more experience with computer architecture should answer) to see if the event has taken place.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common technique to simulate events by polling but that's often very inefficient and leads to a dilemma where you have a tradeoff between event resolution and polling overhead but that doesn't mean true events don't exist.

A CPU interrupt, which could be raised to signal an external event, like I/O completion, is an example of an event all the way down at the hardware layer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both operating system and application level depend on events not polling. Polling is usually possible where states cannot be maintained. On desktop applications and OS levels however, applications have states; so, they use events for their processes, not polling.

Comment: You can say anything you want, really. But it is not all polling on the operating system level, either. The CPU has interrupts which can be triggered by, for example, I/O completion. The OS does not actually need to poll, as it can simply assign some code to run on interrupt.

Comment: If you edit your answer to make this correction, I can remove my downvote (StackOverflow won't let me otherwise).

Comment: I've done that; thanks. Didn't even realize one can edit the answers.